# Displaying relationships between nodes

Tags: data-visualization

I'm trying to create something similar to this.

[image]

So, 3 different Node classes, and a whole bunch of relationships between them. In my case, there should be roughly half of the number of nodes present at most.

What I'm looking for is recommendations as to the best way to create a similar type of graph. Spent some time looking at R/GGplot2, but haven't found any solutions so far. I expect it's because I'm not using the correct vocabulary.

The posted image was created using a proprietary app that I unfortunately am not able to leverage, otherwise I'd simply use that.

Any suggestions/solutions would be fantastic!

Comment: The thread at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9040/visualize-movie-actor-relationships is closely related: although the application is different, it concerns visualizing bipartite graphs.

Comment: You might want to also check out some of the other questions with the tag network, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networks . They will have suggested graphics and tools to do those graphics as well.

Comment: So it was the case that it was a vocabulary issue. The "edge-vertex graph visualization" looks fantastic. Given that, what available libraries/utilities are there that I could use. Googling "edge-vertex graph visualization" doesn't yield many results...

Comment: With Graphviz you can easily make graphs like this: http://www.graphviz.org/content/unix

Comment: unfortunately that's not standard terminology. I was just referring to some methods using that term in order to more easily distinguish them from some of the other approaches being discussed. The overlap in meanings of the term "graph", especially in this visualization context is unfortunate and makes Google searches more challenging.

Comment: Try [Pajek](http://goo.gl/bGAXb). It also supports plethora of export options, so you can easily modify figure in dedicated software (e.g. Inkscape).

Answer (score 1):

Gephi, an open source network visualization software, can do that: http://gephi.org

See [this recent discussion](http://forum.gephi.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=1016) on what a user was able to do with a bipartite graph, which is what you have. It is also called a bipartite network, or a two-mode network in Social Network Analysis.

Thought you'll need some trick, because Gephi doesn't have a layout to handle that directly. Feel free to ask the user how did I get that.

(disclamer: I'm part of this community)

Comment: Great, thanks for the idea Seb. Checking it out now.